# CATIA /VBA- modify Point property

Tags: vba, catia

I created a macro That modify property of balloon object in CAT drawing but the problem I cant modify the Point property and it's line (see below )

[image]
My code  :

```
    myBalloon.Text = Right(myBalloon.Text, 3)
    myBalloon.SetFontSize 0, 0, 2.5
    myBalloon.FrameType = 0
```

Solution that I tried :

```
  Dim myview As DrawingView

  Set myview = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView

  Dim mytext As DrawingText

  Set mytext = myview.Texts.Item(1)
  Dim myleader As DrawingLeader

  Set myleader = mytext.Leaders.Item(1)
  myleader.HeadSymbol = 0
```

This works only for 1 point  is there  away to modify the other points in that Activeview
Anyone Can light me on this ?

Comment: What’s the error message?

Comment: There is no error , the solution works only for one point and I want to modify the other points so I need to create a loop through other point so I can modify them

Comment: Have you just tried to use a nested for loop through both the texts collection and then the leaders collection?

Comment: nested ? what do you mean, can provide an example ?if you  mean like tested it , I don't knwo wich part that needs to be modified for the loop in order to add the variable for incrementation

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
Dim myview As DrawingView

  Set myview = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views.ActiveView

  Dim mytext As DrawingText
  Dim myleader As DrawingLeader


  For Each mytext In myview.Texts

    For Each myleader In dText.Leaders

        myleader.HeadSymbol = 0

    Next

  Next
```

The above code is untested, but should be a start for you.

Comment: I got an error in doing this but I will try again by changing some lines and I will let you know

Comment: @POLOSTutorials What error and where? Maybe you can update your question with the revised code and a more direct question with regards to the error